# MVC: Dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, ienumerable, partial

I am getting this error and I'm not sure if I am able to do this, here is my code..

Application controller

```
public ActionResult AppView()
{
    List<Application> apps;
    using (ISiteDbContext context = _resolver.GetService<ISiteDbContext>())
    {
        apps = context.Applications.ToList();
    } 
    return PartialView("AppView", apps.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList());
}
```

Render partial - this is within a view which is in the home controller.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new Example.Services.DAL.Application());}
```

and my application view

```
@model IEnumerable<Example.Services.DAL.Application>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Applications";
}

<h2>Applications</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Application", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

full error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Example.Services.DAL.Application', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Example.Services.DAL.Application]'.

Comment: Please include the *full* error message in the body of your question. The full error message won't start with "but"

Comment: full error message added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error states you are passing a wrong type. Change

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new Example.Services.DAL.Application());}
```

to:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new List<Example.Services.DAL.Application> { new Example.Services.DAL.Application() });}
```

Comment: Wow great answer! It works but is it normal that it automatically adds a new row to the list when it renders the partial view?

Comment: @Nurul not sure if I 100% understand your question, however based on `AppView.cshtml` in question it should add a new row - you pass collection of `Application` and it lists all items (in this example it's just one row).

Comment: Oh i see..the code works but what if i don't want a new row to be generated? Just the table(if its empty then an empty table, but if not empty then it will show all the rows). Because i have an add button to add row.

Comment: @Nurul If you are talking about first row where `Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)` is, you need to wrap entire `tr` into `@if (Model.Any()) { ... }`. However if you have different code in your partial view I'd suggest creating separate question with your example.

Answer (score 2):

Your `AppView.cshtml` is bind to strongly type of `@model IEnumerable<Example.Services.DAL.Application>` and while calling this view you are passing `@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new Example.Services.DAL.Application());}`

It should be the list object. You must pass `list` of `Example.Services.DAL.Application()`

Change your

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new Example.Services.DAL.Application());}
```

to

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Application/AppView.cshtml", new List<Example.Services.DAL.Application> { new Example.Services.DAL.Application() });}
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is looking for a Ienumerable  because what you pass to your partial view must be the same as what is in your view so try to change the first line of your application view to

```
@model Example.Services.DAL.Application
```

it worked for me hopefully it was of good use to you as well :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to use sorting on a collection of (custom) Objects, you need a method for sorting it. Usually, this is accomplished by inheriting the "IComparable" interface. In your Object class, you then need a method "Compare" to determine the method of comparing the instances of your Objects for sorting (I use "Date" in my project).

To recap:

You use this in your Application Controller:

> return PartialView("AppView", apps.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList());

But in order to actually sort (or in this case OrderBy), you need a method in your "Application" class that compares the instances in the list to sort them. This is done using the "Compare" method:

> int Compare(Object x, Object y)

How you compare is totally up to you. The result however, is either:

- Less than zero: **Object x < Object y**
- Zero: **Object x = Object y**
- Greater than zero: **Object x > Object y**

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Dear regards,
Björn