# Change from List to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application stops and give me this error message:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Test.Models.GamesVM]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
[Test.Models.Runner]'.
```

My Controller:

```
return PartialView("PartialViewAllRunners", db.Runners.ToList());
```

My View:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewAllRunners.cshtml", Model)
```

Both `View` and the `Partial View` has `IEnumerable`, so what is the problem and what needs to be changed?

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378288/but-this-dictionary-requires-a-model-item-of-type-system-collections-generic-ie) provides you the answer.

Comment: The message is self explanatory - your passing a collection of `GamesVM` to a view which expects a collection of `Runner` (`IEnumerable` vs` List` has nothing to do with it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, so any Partial View I add, must be of the same model?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have a model containing properties for `List<GamesVM> Games` and `List<Runner> Runners` and then pass them to different partials using (say) `@Html.Partial("Games", model.Games)` and ` @Html.Partial("Runners", model.Runners)`. But you have not shown us enough of your code to know exactly where your error is being thrown

Comment: @StephenMuecke So if I understand you correct I can add several Partial Views from different Controllers and Models in the same View? That's is just what I'm trying to do. If I try to add ´...model.Games) in the View, Intellisense don't give me an option! Would it be a problem if the Views main model in the top is a View Model? I have to check my code a little bit more. If I haven't shown enough code, what could I add to make it easier to see the problem?

Comment: Does `PartialViewAllRunners.cshtml` have `@model IEnumerable<Runner>`? If so, somewhere else in your code, you are passing a model with is `IEnumerable<GamesVM>` to that partial. In the code under _My View:_, what is `Model`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Yes, PartialViewAllRunners.cshtml have model IEnumerable<Runner>  In My View, I have the IEnumerable<GamesVM> in the top for the other content in the My View. How do you get the grey background for the code in the text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109318/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-3d-kreativ).

Answer (score -1):

Edit - Change your view model to this:

@model IEnumerable < ModelClass Name>

return View(db.modelclass.ToList());