# Passing partial view as IEnumerable to single model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a list of items on the create view.

I'm using VS2017, EF6, MVC5, Code First.

I've got a partial view named _Patients

```
@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient>
<table class="table>">
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientFirstName)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My main view is Create.cshtml

and I'm adding the partial view with

```
@Html.Partial("_Patients")
```

My main view is using a single item model

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient
```

When I change the main view model to `IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient>`

the list displays properly but the form fields give me errors because its the wrong type.

I'm wanting to just pass the partial view as `IEnumerable`, is that possible?

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to do here - are you wanting to pass the single instance of `Patient` from the main model to your partial (and why)?

Comment: <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientFirstName</td> is missing an end parentheses? Copy/paste formatting issue in your question?

Comment: What's not clear about my question? I need to populate a list of Patients on the Create view. I think I was pretty clear in my initial post when I said "I'm trying to create a list of items on the create view." Why would you think I'm trying to pass a single instance of Patient from the main to the partial?

Comment: TamusJRoyce, No it's not....

Comment: @AdamBlasingame Can you try my post and let me know if it works

Comment: Everything is unclear! What do you mean by _create a list of items_? What are you trying to display in your view - a form to create a new patient plus a list of existing patients?

Comment: I need a list of all patients on the create view so that the user can select a patient and auto populate some of the form fields using jquery. i.e. "Select a patient from the list", user selects the patient and I'll populate the fields, i.e. First Name, Last Name, DOB, etc. with Jquery based on the selection.

Comment: @AdamBlasingame Have you got the solution?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I ended up using Jquery and an ajax request to populate the list instead. It takes a couple more steps but does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your partial in following ways

```
@Html.Partial('_Patients', new List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient>())
```

Comment: Same Error:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient'.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378288/but-this-dictionary-requires-a-model-item-of-type-system-collections-generic-ie

Comment: I've tried that already, just for fun I changed my partial view code, again, to @{Html.RenderPartial("_Patients", new List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient> { new ContosoUniversity.Models.Patient() });    }       It's not the same problem exactly as in the link you posted because in their code they were already calling IEnumerable in their main view, which I am not. I already said I am using a single object view that I need to use a IEnumerable partial view in. I don't post questions without spending hours pouring over the forums for similar issues, which I have already spent days doing.